# Pi-hole set dns for one device to 127.0.0.1 after uninstalling I can't change this back to my dns

Tags: domain-server

I installed pi-hole, it wouldn't resolve, so I uninstalled. When installing I used the device tun0 which is my vpn. This may have been part of the problem, but I don't care I don't want to use it anymore.

My problem now is when installing pi-hole it changed tun0 to always use the dns 127.0.0.1, the localhost, and for the life of me I cannot figure out how to reset this.

If I edit /etc/resolv.conf, of course, it resets when the computer restarts, but for that session it works and tun0 will resolve hosts through the supplied dns (my ISP's dns)

I've tried multiple tutorials that all recommend changing various config files for different software in order to make the dns resolve to a specific host, but none of this changes the fact that when I start openvpn service the /etc/resolv.conf changes back to using 127.0.0.1

Can anyone suggest what program, what config file, might have been used by pi-hole to make my tun0 device always set the nameserver in /etc/resolv.conf to 127.0.0.1?

contents of the netplan config file:

```
    ~$ cat /etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml 
    # Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
    network:
      version: 2
      renderer: NetworkManager
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pi-hole made a change to /etc/dhcpcd.conf

It specifically added the following to the file:

```
    interface tun0
            static ip_address=100.64.32.2/23
            static routers=100.64.32.1
            static domain_name_servers=127.0.0.1
```

when I deleted this part of the file and started the openvpn service it now populates /etc/resolv.conf with the correct dns servers, the file is no longer resolving to 127.0.0.1 only (which looks like the last line of the section I deleted, but I deleted all of it as there is no similar entry for my ethernet device, and I imagined all of it was added by pi-hole and does nothing if pi-hole is not running)

Answer (score 1):

What system did you install? Ubuntu 16.04, 18.04? Do you use netplan or ifupdown? Your /etc/resolv.conf is generated from various programs that manage your network setup.

Also if your network configuration has an error the config process stops residing with a not properly configured resolv.conf

Comment: Hey, I'm using 18.04LTS

A quick websearch indicated that 18.04 uses netplan, and when I run the command at the console it shows that netplan is installed.

I assume from your response this will be the way to configure the DNS for my devices, I will look into this further.

Thank you so much for your response, I will report back soon if this helped.

Comment: Does it resov names without VPN tunnel? Can you post your netplan yaml file?

Comment: OK, I tried adding a line that I was told to add to the netplan config file like: 'code'       nameservers:
          addresses: [1.1.1.1, 1.0.0.1] 
which is giving an error when I apply it:
: unknown key 'nameservers'
It looks like it is configured to use Network Manager, but when I use Network Manager to set manual DNS servers /etc/resolv.conf still comes back as local loopback when I start openvpn service

Comment: Yes the DNS servers are resolving as usual when I don't use the VPN tunnel, it only sets the DNS to local loopbac when I start the VPN service. The netplan config is as follows:

    ~$ cat /etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml 
    # Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
    network:
      version: 2
      renderer: NetworkManager

Comment: Sorry, for the life of me I cannot figure out how to post the contents of the config file with indention in this comment...I'll just edit the original question and add it in there.